# Alamofire 3.0 handle JSON

Tags: json, get, alamofire

Sorry for my bad english :)

So here we go. I started to create iPhone Apps in Swift 2.
I would like to use an API. For the Request I have used the Alamofire 3.0 Library. And this works fine, but I am unable to handle the JSON. I tried to use SwiftyJSON but I have no idea how it works. There is my code:

```
let headers = [
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
]

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "API URL", headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in

            if response.result.isSuccess {

            }

    }
```

I hope someone can help me. ;) Thanks

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33079355/3734028

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My latest usage of Alamofire (3.0) and SwiftyJSON (2.3)

```
let parameters = ["param1" : param, "param2" : "stringParam"] // my params, not required
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters)
    .responseJSON{ response in
        guard response.result.error == nil else {
            print("Error. \(response.result.error?.localizedDescription)")
                return
            } // guard close
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                let post = JSON(response.result.value!) // JSON is stored in post variable
            // Another check of result
            //if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value {
            //    let post = JSON(value)
            } // if close
     } // responseJSON close
```

Then access the JSON as per the instructions in [Github](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

Hope this helps

Jacko